# Read a single file containing multiple XML line code blocks into multiple xml files in Talend

Tags: xml, etl, talend

There is a single file (compressed) that effectively contains multiple XML files of the same format, so the file itself is not a valid XML; for example:
The large file has below content

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Proposal xmlns="a namespace">
    <ASubnode>Text</ASubNode>
    <LotsOfOtherNodes />
</Proposal>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Proposal xmlns="a namespace">
    <ASubnode>Text</ASubNode>
    <LotsOfOtherNodes />
</Proposal>
....
```

I would like to process all the nodes, one at a time as a single XML; 
For example:

```
<Proposal xmlns="a namespace">
    <ASubnode>Text</ASubNode>
    <LotsOfOtherNodes />
</Proposal>
```

The above block should be read as the first XML file by Talend and so on..

I cannot use tFileInputXML because it throws an exception upon reaching the intermediate XML declaration nodes. Could you please suggest ways on how to approach this problem?

Note: I have used an example for a similar Stack Overflow problem posted on Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you split your multi-xml file into individual xml files, then read each individual file with `tFileInputXML`. Here's what I did to achieve that :

[image]

First read the file with `tFileInputDelimited` that has a single column (content), setting the row separator to "`</Proposal>`". This will populate the content column with the content of a single xml file (without the closing tag, since it's set as the row separator).
Then iterate over each line, and read it with a `tFixedFlowInput` that has 2 columns: xmlFile (set to content) and closingTag which contains the closing tag that has been removed by `tFileInputDelimited`. This is then sent to a `tFileOutputDelimited` which writes the xml content and the closing tag next to it (notice the empty Field separator).
The file name is dynamic so that you have numbered files. `NB_FILE` global variable is first set to 1 in `tSetGlobalVar_1`, then incremented on each generated file in `tSetGlobalVar_2`.
At the end, you can simply use a `tFileList` with a mask like "out_*.xml" in order to iterate over and read the generated xml files with a `tFileInputXML`.

[image]

Here I just print the file paths to console.

**Alternative solution**

Here's a more efficient implementation of the file split part. It uses a `tFileInputFullRow` to read the file row by row (`\n` delimiter), then write each row to a file (notice the append mode in `tFileOutputDelimited_1`). If the line that was just written is the xml closing tag, increment the file number so that the next row is written to a different file, otherwise keep the same file number.

[image]

Comment: Thank You for the detailed description! It's working as expected. Just want to get your inputs on if there are alternative approaches. The files are quite large in size, so was thinking if there are alternative ways to handle scale?

Comment: I've come up with another solution, which should be more efficient ! The idea is the same, split the large file into smaller files, but the implementation is a bit different. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Hello @iMezouar,
Thanks for this approach. 

My source file is actually multiple zip files in Terra-bytes, in first process, I am decompressing these, occupying even more space. Next, with this approach, I would again occupy same amout of space when the files are split. 

Given the volumes of data to process, I was thinking on the lines, if the creation of intermediate XML files could be avoided?

also, is there a way, I could pass contents of compressed file to next component in Talend, without having to decompress the zip file first?

Thanks again for your time and suggestions.